# .htaccess redirect for subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a help section on my site that I'm moving.  It used to be in the root of the domain, now I'm moving it to a directory called "help".  I would like to setup a redirect rule that keeps the url path.

Example:  I would like
`www.domain.net/topic1` to redirect to `www.domain.net/help/topic1` etc...

Most solutions I have come up with end up being a redirect loop or do not keep the permalink.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$ help/ [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((?!help/).*)$ help/$1 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

sadly, if the urls doesn't have anything in common... it seems you'll have to make one rule for each url then add a 302 (temporary) or a 301 (permanent) redirection.

i don't like too much the idea of one line for each url but this could work

```
Redirect 301 /topic1 /help/topic1
Redirect 301 /topic2 /help/topic2
```

you could try with something like this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(topic1|topic2|....|topicN)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /help/$1 [R=301,L]
```